# Dynamic sql pivot join

Tags: sql, dynamic, pivot

I am trying to achieve a dynamic sql pivot where two tables are joined together and a group of images become their own column.

Table 1:

```
house_id     name    value
1            image   image1.jpg
1            image   image2.jpg
1            image   image3.jpg
```

Table 2:

```
id      updated_at     house_name
1       2016-12-02     House 1
```

I want it to look like this:

```
house_id     updated_at    house_name    image1         image2        image3
1            2016-12-02    House 1       image1.jpg     image2.jpg    image3.jpg
```

I want to achieve this through a dynamic sql pivot, but I can't get it to work (even without the join):

```
DECLARE @cols  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)='';
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)='';

SELECT @cols = @cols + QUOTENAME(name) + ',' FROM (select distinct name from #table1 ) as house_meta
select @cols = substring(@cols, 0, len(@cols)) --trim "," at end

set @query = 
'SELECT * from 
(
    select house_id, name, value from #table1
) src
pivot 
(
    max(value) for name in (' + @cols + ')
) piv'

execute(@query)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to use aggregate operators with `image` data type, so you can not use `PIVOT` here

Comment: Is there any way to accomplish this without using a pivot?

Comment: it depends. If the task is just one time operation that migrate data, then i'd tried to create a new table and then fill it by cursor row-by-row